# Date in rendering variants

Tags: sxa, renderfield

I used template containing field from type `DateTime` and render time in `Rendering Variant` like that

[image]

When I enter date only in field and time is empty, it render default value `12:00 AM` so I need to not render time when it is empty, As I remove check from 
"Render if empty" check box but it did not work and I tried to use `Rules` but also did not work so there are another way to do?

Comment: You can make logic on code side to check datetime field has time. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15893339/check-if-date-time-string-contains-time

Comment: How do you render it? Add code from your view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to display time, but just a data simply change the Date format. `Render if empty` is to render field renderer in the Experience Editor even if the field doesn't have a value. Thanks to this, you will see "No text in field", and you will be able to fill it (in the Experience Editor).

If you would like to display date all the time but conditionally display time when it is provided together with a date you will need to write some custom code. This is not available out of the box. You can:

- write your own Variant Token - take a look [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/18/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/create-a-custom-token-for-a-rendering-variant.html)
- override `RenderDate` processor and dynamically change the date format - you can check if time is also provided and if so use date format which has time